# Recursion to find depth of expression

Tags: python, recursion, tracking, depth

I am trying to use recursion to find the depth of an "expression", i.e., how many layers of nested tuples there are:  For example,

```
depth(('+', ('expt', 'x', 2), ('expt', 'y', 2))) => 2

depth(('/', ('expt', 'x', 5), ('expt', ('-', ('expt', 'x', 2), 1), ('/', 5, 2)))) => 4
```

Basically, I figured that I need to check (working from out to in) for each element being an instance of a tuple, and then if so, recursively call the depth function.  But I need to find a way of figuring out which set of recursive calls has the **greatest** depth, and that's where I'm stuck.  Here's what I have so far:

```
def depth3(expr):
    if not isinstance(expr, tuple):
        return 0
    else:
        for x in range(0, len(expr)):
            # But this doesn't take into account a search for max depth
            count += 1 + depth(expr[x])
    return count
```

Thoughts on a good way to approach this?

Comment: Pass a variable through the method like `depth(expr, layers)` and start the call at 1, for each expression inside it, call `depth` increment layers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're on the right track, but instead of finding the "total" depth with `count += 1 + depth(expr[x])`
, use `max` to find the maximum:

```
def depth(expr):
    if not isinstance(expr, tuple):
        return 0
    # this says: return the maximum depth of any sub-expression + 1
    return max(map(depth, expr)) + 1

print depth(("a", "b"))
# 1
print depth(('+', ('expt', 'x', 2), ('expt', 'y', 2)))
# 2
print depth(('/', ('expt', 'x', 5), ('expt', ('-', ('expt', 'x', 2), 1), ('/', 5, 2)))) 
# 4
```

Comment: Okay, interesting.. But it didn't seem to work for the last example (returned 3 instead of 4)?  And just to understand better, how are you able to approach this without breaking down every tuple into each of it's individual elements (like the for loop did) ?

Comment: What do you mean about the last example being wrong? I get 4 (did you copy and paste correctly?). Also: the `map` function does operate on each of the tuple's individual elements. `map(depth, expr)` means "apply the function `depth` to each element of `expr`.

Comment: Oops.. sorry, was running an older version of the function when I tested!
Ok, thanks! Didn't know how the map function worked, I'm coming to python from other languages.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this - it's a functional-programming solution, in the style you'd use when programming in a language such as Lisp, Haskell, etc.

```
def depth(exp):
    if not exp:                         # the tuple is empty
        return 0                        #return 0
    elif not isinstance(exp[0], tuple): # first element is not a tuple
        return depth(exp[1:])           # traverse the rest of elements
    else:  # depth is 1 + depth of first tuple + depth of rest of elements
        return 1 + max(depth(exp[0]), depth(exp[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode only (not guaranteed to compile, much less run):

```
dep depth(expr):
  if not isinstance(expr, tuple):
    return 0
  else:
    mdepth = 0
    for x in range(0, len(expr)):
      d = depth(expr[x])
      if d > mdepth:
        mdepth = d
    return mdepth+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
def depth(expr):
count = 0
if not isinstance(expr,tuple):
    return 0 
else:
    count = 1
    count1 = 0
    for e in expr:
        count1 = 1 + depth(e)
        count = max(count1,count)
return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply keep track of last maximum depth as you traverse through sub-expressions.

```
def depth(expr):
    # base case
    if not isinstance(expr, tuple):
        return 0
    # if it is a tuple, we've at least depth of 1
    max_depth = 1
    # If any sub-expression is deeper, update max_depth
    for elem in expr:
        elem_depth = 1 + depth(elem)
        if elem_depth > max_depth:
            max_depth = elem_depth
    return max_depth
```